# HBase Replication - Replicate data in 3 data centers

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I our application we are having data from 3 different countries and we are persisting data in HBase.

In each country, we will be keeping data of all the 3 countries.

To achieve this, is it possible that we create our Hadoop cluster using data centers in all these 3 countries and we keep data replication as 3. So due to rack-awareness feature, our data will get auto replicated in all the 3 countries?

Any pointers will be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t have HBASE cluster across countries. This won’t work because of latency, failover problems, network issues, etc.
A good option would be to have 3 clusters, one HBase table per country and sync the tables between clusters as proposed above

As far as I know only Google has successfully implemented a multi-country database providing both consistency and availability: Spanner. But the key elements of the solution are: a private physical network between the Data Centers and their own implementation of NTP which guarantee that all servers across the world have the same clock with just a few milliseconds precision.

Comment: Thanks Harold for your inputs. After our analysis, to us also, this seems to be the viable option.

Answer (score 0):

This solution looks theoretically feasible but writes may become pretty slow as data needs to replicated to 3 nodes located in different geographies. It needs to be tried out and check whether the latency is within tolerable limit.

Another option could be, to have three different HBase clusters at three locations and design tables in such a way that tables from one HBase cluster could be copied to another one during night hours to keep the data in sync daily. In this case, an HBase cluster will have current data from it's own location but the data from other two cities will lag by a day.

Comment: CopyTable is one mechanism to sync two HBase clusters. Replication feature of HBase may be more suitable for use case.